An error "Invalid expr" occurred in Advanced Filtering on Array Fields in Milvus Lite
I am using pymilvus version: 2.4.4
When trying to re-produce the code in documentations for advanced filtering on array fields https://milvus.io/docs/array_data_type.md#Advanced-filtering:
    collection_name="test_collection",
    filter="ARRAY_CONTAINS_ANY(color_coord, [7, 8, 9])",
    output_fields=["id", "color", "color_tag", "color_coord"],
    limit=3
)

It gives the following error:
MilvusException: <MilvusException: (code=1100, message=Invalid expr: ARRAY_CONTAINS_ANY(color_coord, [7, 8, 9]): invalid parameter)>

So, how to perform this operation correctly?
